# Loop and IF formula for 0.00%

Tags: vba

Can someone help me with the below code?

I am trying to add a text "Valid" in Column "I" if Cells in Column E is not Blank and Column H is 0.00%. Column H is converted to Format Cells>Percentage>Decimal Places = 2.

I am getting the error message:

> Runtime error "13": Type Mismatch.

in the line:

```
If (Range("E" & Y) <> "" And Range("H" & Y) = "0.00%" Then)
```

The full code is:

```
Sub My_Comments()

  Dim X As Integer
  Dim Y As Integer
  Dim Z As Integer

  For X = 2 To 10000

    If IsError(Range("F" & X)) Then

      Range("I" & X) = "Not Held"

    End If

  Next X

  For Y = 2 To 10000

    If Range("E" & Y) <> "" And Range("H" & Y) = "0.00%" Then

      Range("I" & Y) = "Valid"

    End If

  Next Y

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have errors in columns E or Columns H?

Comment: You need to tell us where the error occurs but I can tell you now that trying to find a string value `"0,00%"` is never going to work when the cells are formatted as percentage. What you looking for is `0`. Also please change `Integer` to `Long` as there is no need for `Integer` ever.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response fellas. I get error in If (Range("E" & Y) <> "" And Range("H" & Y) = "0.00%" Then). I'm guessing its not able to read the 0.00% values from the cells. 

I will try the below suggestion and get back with the result.

If CStr(Range("E" & Y)) <> "" And CStr(Range("H" & Y)) = "0.00%" Then

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the line

```
If Range("E" & Y) <> "" And Range("H" & Y) = "0.00%" Then)
```

with this:

```
If CStr(Range("E" & Y)) <> "" And Range("H" & Y).Text = "0.00%" Then '// .Text
```

Comment: Replacing the above does not give me any error message nor does it do anything in Column "I".

Comment: “0,00%” is a string value which would never be found within a cell formatted as percentage..... 0 however is!

Comment: @JvdV by whatever miracle, it works on my computer too :)

Comment: I can understand it does with the .Text, but even without? Curious but fun at the same time

Comment: So are you suggesting that I Remove the % format and keep it as text and then later convert to %?

Comment: @Tejas Oh, not at all! Do not change the worksheet's formatting! The`.Text` property of the `Range` object will read what is DISPAYED (SHOWN) in the cell and not what is STORED, so VBA will read the %-formated "image" of the stored number as a String, not Number, and compare it to `"0.00%"`, just as you wished.

Comment: @Tejas Well, now we come to the real problem you have: the data. Could you share the data that "does not want" to comply with the code?

Comment: Hi guys,

I got my problem sorted by one of my colleagues help.

Sub My_Comments()
Dim X As Integer
For y = 2 To 10000
    'i = 0
    i = Range("H" & y)
   
    If WorksheetFunction.IsError(i) = True Then
        i = 100
    End If
    If (Range("E" & y) <> "" And (Abs(i) * 100) <= 0.01) Then
    Range("I" & y) = "Valid"
    ElseIf Range("b" & y) = "" Then
    Range("I" & y) = ""
        
   ElseIf IsError(Range("F" & y)) Then

      Range("I" & y) = "Not Held"

        
    
    Else
        
        Range("I" & y) = "Price"
    

  End If
  Next y
  End Sub

Comment: @Tejas Aha, so it was "a problem" with the data, after all. Thank you for letting us know. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your time everyone.